# How to prevent service be closed when app crashes-android

Tags: android, service, android-service, android-service-binding

I have a service in foreground which NOT stop when the app is closed
but it DOES stop when the app crashes, I want the service continue running if the app crashes, how can I get this result?

Comment: What do you mean by _"Dont want the service stop when the app crash"_. Does the service restart later on?

Comment: if the app crashes the service is stopped I want to avoid that and the service continue running

Comment: Then fix the crash

Comment: You cannot avoid the service to stop on the app crash, because the process is getting killed. What you can is to restart it after the crash.

Comment: Yes I have find all the crash I found, but what if  there is any "crash" which I haven't detected and in production appears?  in playstore there is some apps which runs and start a service which sometime the app crashes and the service continue running (I'm not sure) but Nike App is one of them

Comment: Again, when an app crashes, everything accotiated with its process gets killed. But you can indicate that if it happens Android restart the service that, in its turn, will keep running.

Answer (score 1):

Make the service run in a different process.

This way if the app crashes, it will only exit out of the main process.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service
    android:name=".MyService"
    android:process=":MyServiceProcess"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in Service Class. This will stop the app from crashing

```
@Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent){
        stopSelf();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
//Your Runnable
        mRunnable=null;
    }
```